# How to specify model author of CoreML model?

Tags: coreml, coremltools

I'm not able to set Author of model using `coremltools`.

### To Reproduce

```
temp_model = ct.models.MLModel(current_model_path)

print(f'Original author: {temp_model.author}')
temp_model.author = 'Luka'
print(f'Modified author: {temp_model.author}')
temp_model.save('temp_model.mlpackage')
temp_model = ct.models.MLModel('temp_model.mlpackage')
print(f'After saving: {temp_model.author}')
```

[image]

### System environment (please complete the following information):

- coremltools version: 6.3.0
- operating system: MacOS

### Additional context

The model that I'm trying to modify the author is a pytorch model that I trained and converted to CoreML.
It's not only the author, but anything in this image is also something I'm unable change through code:
[image]

Edit 1: it's a bug that Apple acknowledged, and the fix is deployed in the latest beta release (7.0b1): https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1908

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to update the author name / metadata of the coreml model:

**Method #1**: Open the model with Xcode and tap on the "Edit" button from the upper right corner: Author and other metadata fields will become editable, once you finish editing, hit the "Save / Edit" button. You are good to go :)

[Screenshot on how to update the model author / metadata info within Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTIVr.png)

**Method #2**: My suggestion is to save the updated model with a different name on disk. Here is an example:

1. Load the model from disk
2. Update the model author property
3. Save the model with a different name

```py
    # Load the saved coreml model from disk.
    model = ct.models.MLModel('ImageBrightness.mlpackage')
    # Set the author name.
    model.author = "Sample Author Name Goes Here"
    # Save the model with a different name
    model.save("ImageBrightnessUpdated.mlpackage")
    print(model.author)
```

Finally, let's load the newly updated model and print its author:

```py
    # Load the new updated model and print the author name.
    model = ct.models.MLModel('ImageBrightnessUpdated.mlpackage')
    print(model.author)
```

This should gives us "Sample Author Name Goes Here".

**NOTE**: While updating metadata / author name using code (method #2 works), it dose not seem to display the updated name when previewed with Xcode. I think it might be an issue / bug as I am using Xcode 15 Beta version now.

But you can still easily update model metadata within Xcode itself.

[You can experiment with these methods using this sample CoreMl model from this Github link.](https:////github.com/delegatepattern/ImageBrightness)